# Constant minimap markers and colors for dire and radiant

Tags: dota-2

On the minimap, enemies are marked with a **X** and their *HP* bars are **red**.
 *(In opposite of my teams circles and green bars)*

Because I started the game playing *Radiant* only, I'm now getting confused when I'm on *Dires* site with the said minimap markers and colors.

**Is it possible to configure the game** (via options or console or *cfg* s) **such that ...**

- *Radiant* has circles and green bars
- *Dire* has crosses and red bars.

**... no matter in which team I am?**

Answer (score 2):

The answer simply put is no. However you could hold "ALT" button and you will see the enemy icon on screen instead of X or Circle which might help somewhat(this is League of Legends style). I found this problem somewhat irritating as well.

Comment: I found `ALT` to be useful as well, lets me quickly see which hero is where rather than having to remember their colors.

Comment: Glad I could help. You could also flag your question as answered. Have a gg!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you described requires a HUD change. However here are some useful console commands to change the colours of team mates or the Enemy.

> Opposing team color combination:
>   The RGB for the enemy team is dota_enemy_color_r, dota_enemy_color_g, dota_enemy_color_b (ie: dota_enemy_color_r 1). Below are some colors the enemy team can be:
>   R, G, B all set to 0: Black
>   R, G, B all set to 1: White
>   R 1, G 0, B 0: Red
>   R 1, G 1, B 0: Yellow
>   R 1, G 0, B 1: Fuchsia
>   R 0, G 1, B 0: Green
>   R 0, G 1, B 1: Cyan
>   R 0, G 0, B 1: Blue
>   The RGB for the friendly team is dota_friendly_color_r, dota_friendly_color_g, dota_friendly_color_b (ie: dota_friendly_color_r 1). Same colors as above.

[source](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/ltiul/list_of_useful_console_commands_for_dota_2/)

Comment: do you have to do this every time you start up the game since it uses the console?  Or is there a way to save this to a file to be loaded.

Comment: @yx. `Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg\autoexec.cfg`

Comment: @yx The commands in that file will be executed on every game startup.

Comment: nice! (12 chars)

Comment: @yx. <3 ty for tidy